# Loop which sum too much

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an issue with a loop I made in VBA: I have a folder fills with several excel file, and for each of those files I hqve column A which I want sum until a certain condition is reach on column H.
The code seems to work but the problem is that it keeps the sum of the last sheet it runned, For example I get in output:

```
 (Sheet1)   45
 (sheet2)   90 (+45)
 (sheet3)   135 (+45)
```

Instead of

```
 (sheet 1)   45
 (sheet 2)   45
 (sheet 3)   45

 **
    Sub BIA_data_files()
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim wB As Workbook
        Dim SumResult As Double
        Dim OutPut As Range
        Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Set FolderObj = 
FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\practica.trafico\Desktop\SecuriteeTest\")
        Set OutPut = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")

        For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
            Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)
            Dim rngH, i, j, k As Integer

            With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")            
               For i = 2 To 500
                  rngH = Left(.Cells(i, "H").Value, 2)
                  If rngH = 11 Then
                     k = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                  End If
                  j = j + k
                  k = 0
               Next i

               OutPut.Value = j
               Set OutPut = OutPut.Offset(1, 0)
            End With

            wB.Save
            wB.Close
        Next fileobj
     End Sub
```

Do not know where it might come from ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from `j = j + k`. You never reset `j` to 0 so it continues summing it up. Just add `j=0` at:

```
OutPut.Value = j
j=0
```

Comment: @IlvarNourtan Glad it helped!

Comment: @IlvarNourtan, if this answered your question you should accept it

Comment: to explain a little, unlike many languages, VBA variable declaration is for the whole procedure (i.e. it doesnt really matter where the variable is declared within the procedure) - a declaration within a loop will not be redeclared each time